# Graphing useful airline data in R?

Tags: r

This is the original data set.

`structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 21L, 22L, 23L), YEAR = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), MONTH = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), DAY_OF_MONTH = c(12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L), DAY_OF_WEEK = c(7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER = c("AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA"), ORIGIN_CITY_NAME = c("Greer, SC", "Greer, SC", 
"Greer, SC", "New York, NY", "New York, NY", "New York, NY"), DEST_CITY_NAME = c("Dallas/Fort Worth, TX", "Dallas/Fort Worth, TX", "Dallas/Fort Worth, TX", "Phoenix, AZ", "Phoenix, AZ", "Phoenix, AZ"), DEP_DELAY = c(-8L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 189L, 0L), ARR_DELAY = c(-17L, -11L, -22L, 44L, 205L, 86L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))`

I then created another data frame and mutated another column and created on time departures with values of "on time" or "delayed." So they'll essentially only be a data frame with columns of the OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER, DEP_DELAY, AND DEP_TYPE, ARR_DELAY, and ARR_TYPE

`structure(list(OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA"), DEP_DELAY = c(-8L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 189L, 0L), dep_type = c("on time", "on time", "on time", "delayed", "delayed", "on time"), ARR_DELAY = c(-17L, -11L, -22L, 44L, 205L, 86L), arr_type = c("on time", "on time", 
"on time", "delayed", "delayed", "delayed")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")`

I also made another data_frame that summarized the list of airlines and their percentage of on time flights and on time percentage.

`structure(list(OP_UNIQUE_CARRIER = c("F9", "B6", "WN", "OH", 
"AA", "NK"), ot_dep_rate = c(0.479982873046457, 0.493874693734687, 0.554597925278839, 0.585452505609574, 0.58751859857949, 0.608972544579677), ot_departures = c(2242L, 5644L, 28442L, 6262L, 20928L, 4303L), ot_arr_rate = c(0.490687219010918, 0.493437171858593, 0.617366040090477, 0.567969334330591, 0.556441425002105, 0.571610529295216), ot_arrivals = c(2292L, 5639L, 31661L, 6075L, 19821L, 4039L), n_flights = c(4671L, 11428L, 51284L, 10696L, 35621L, 7066L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

I know have no idea how to plot these points or make useful graphical sense of this idea. If anyone could help me with making a scatterplot or bar graph, and figuring out a hypothesis test that would be amazing. Should I use a chi-square test?

Anything helps, thank you!

Comment: Please include your actual data by using `dput(data)` as this is not reproducible

Comment: The dataset is large with 284,000 entries; can i parse it so its not as large? I'm sorry, I'm extremely new to this.

Comment: then do `dput(head(data))` and that will give at least the idea of your stucture

Comment: I edited the original post to reflect that code. Thank you!

Comment: So what do you want to know/show in the plots? Are you looking for relationships between variables? Or just want to show a bar graph comparing each of the variables in the final dataset between companies?

Comment: I was initially thinking about doing graph showing the relationship between size of the airline (using number of flights) vs on time performance. I had originally done a scatter plot with using axis as (on-time departures, number of flights) but since the dataframe was categorized with only 18 points (unique carriers) it didn't seem very convincing. Basically, I'm trying to depict some kind of correlating and congruent information in order to help a consumer create an experience with the least delays, etc.

Comment: Can anyone help, please?